# RVM doesn't get installed

Tags: ubuntu, rvm

I'm trying to install RVM in Ubuntu 11.04.
When I give command :

```
bash < <( curl https://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

I get error :

```
bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

I tried doing this  -

```
bash < <( curl -s https://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

but this gives me error -

```
curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

On giving this command :

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm)
```

does not produce any errors and does not install or download anything.

What am I missing ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get this output when trying to get anything from a https:// server, it means that the instance of curl/libcurl that you're using was built without support for this protocol.

Your best bet is to try and upgrade your version of curl/libcurl possibly by building from source and ensuring that ssl support is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks McCauley. My Problem is Solved. For those who are struggling with the same problem, here's what I did - As McCauley suggested,I installed curl by building from source and ensuring that ssl support is enabled. For this -

First, download the binary package of curl from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Extract the binary package :

```
$ tar -xvf curl-7.21.7.tar.gz
$ cd curl-7.21.7
```

Configure with ssl support :

```
$ ./configure --with-ssl
```

Finally, make and install curl :

```
$ make && sudo make install
```

Now, you will be able to install rvm with this command :

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm)
```

-Safal M Joshi